# How to get the correct `RGB` value of a `PNG` image?

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, colors, rgb, mapbox

`Mapbox` provides `Global elevation data` with height data encoded in `PNG` image. Height is decoded by `height = -10000 + ((R * 256 * 256 + G * 256 + B) * 0.1)`. Details are in https://www.mapbox.com/blog/terrain-rgb/.

I want to import the height data to generate terrains in `Unity3D`.

```
Texture2D dem = (Texture2D)AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath("Assets/dem/12/12_3417_1536.png", typeof(Texture2D));
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            Color c = dem.GetPixel(i, j);

            float R = c.r*255;
            float G = c.g*255;
            float B = c.b*255;
            array[i, j] = -10000 + ((R * 256 * 256 + G * 256 + B) * 0.1f);
        }
```

Here I set a break point and the `rgba` value of the first pixel is `RGBA(0.000, 0.592, 0.718, 1.000)`. `c.r` is `0`. The height is incorrect as this point represent the height of somewhere on a mountain.

Then I open the image in `Photoshop` and get `RGB` of the first pixel: `R=1,G=152,B=179`.

I write a test program in `C#`.

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap("12_3417_1536.png");
Color a = bitmap.GetPixel(0, 0);
```

It shows `Color a` is `(R,G,B,A)=(1,147,249,255)`

Here is the image I test:
https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.terrain-rgb/12/3417/1536.pngraw?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoib2xlb3RpZ2VyIiwiYSI6ImZ2cllZQ3cifQ.2yDE9wUcfO_BLiinccfOKg

Why I got different `RGBA` value with different method? Which one is correct?
According to the comments below, different read order and compressed data in unity may result in different value of the `rgba` of pixel at `(0,0)`.

Now I want to focus on----How to convert the `rgba(0~1)` to `RGBA(0~255)`?
`r_ps=r_unity*255`? But how can I explain `r=0` in unity and `r=1` in PS of pixel at `(0,0)`
?

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling compression from the texture's import settings in Unity (No compression). Alternatively, if you fetch the data at runtime, you can use `Texture.LoadBytes()` to avoid compression artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you are using the same picture and that there aren't two `12_3417_1536.png` files in separate folders.

Each of these functions has a different concept of which pixel is at `(0,0)`. Not sure what you mean by "first" pixel when you tested with photoshop, but Texture coordinates in unity start at lower left corner.

When I tested the lower left corner pixel using paint, I got the same value as you did with photoshop. However, if you test the *upper* left corner, you get `(1,147,249,255)` which is the result `bitmap.GetPixel` returns.

The unity values that you're getting seem to be way off. Try calling `dem.GetPixel(0,0)` so that you're sure you're analyzing the simplest case.

Comment: Buy how can I convert the `rgba` value in unity(range 0~1) to similar value as in PS(range 0~255)? The point is that the value of `r` is `0` in unity of pixel at `(0,0)`. But in PS the value of r is `1`. If I convert the value with `r_PS=r_unity*255`, the result seems to be unmatched.

Comment: I agree, the results seem completely unmatched. You should just be able to multiply by 255 like you're doing, but unless there's some rounding going on, it really shouldn't be 0. Whats worrying is really the B value. `.718*256=183` which is way more than 179. It could be compression, as david pointed out, or you could be comparing different pixels somehow.

Comment: I set texture-import-setting in unity (truecolor,uncompressed,maxSize=8192), `gbra` at pixel `(0,0)` is `"RGBA(0.004, 0.596, 0.702, 1.000)"`. It seems work. So, there should be a type convertion? `r_PS=Math.Round(r_unity*255)`?